# Unclear cause of "too many records in I/O statement" error

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

While writing formatted output to a variable, I get the error

```
forrtl: severe (27): too many records in I/O statement
```

I've checked obvious things - whether data exceeds the format length and vice versa, number and type of variable are compatible with format specifiers - and I can't see why an error should be thrown.

A minimal illustrative example is:

```
program TXTERR27
    use iso_fortran_env, only: OUTPUT_UNIT    
    implicit none

    double precision :: F1, F2
    integer :: I1
    character (len=25), parameter :: A1 = 'AaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaa'

    character (len=250) :: A2

10  format(/, 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ', I3, 'ZZZZZZZZZZZ',     &
    F10.3, 1X, A25, /, 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ', F6.3, 'ZZZZZZZZ')
20  format('Result :[', A250, ']')

    continue

    I1 = 1
    F1 = 1.0D0
    F2 = 1.0D-3

    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, *) "This works:"
    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, 10) I1, F1, A1, F2
    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, *)

    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, *) "This doesn't:"
    write(A2, 10) I1, F1, A1, F2
    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, 20) A2

    stop
end program TXTERR27
```

This is compiled by using:

```
ifort -warn all -check all -traceback -o txterr27 txterr27.f90
```

and no warnings or errors result. The output is as follows:

```
 This works:

ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ  1ZZZZZZZZZZZ     1.000 AaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaa
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ 0.001ZZZZZZZZ

 This doesn't:
forrtl: severe (27): too many records in I/O statement, unit -5, file Internal Formatted Write
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
txterr27           000000000046EEBE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
txterr27           000000000046D956  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
txterr27           00000000004266A2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
txterr27           0000000000403BBB  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
txterr27           0000000000403122  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
txterr27           0000000000419A44  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
txterr27           0000000000417BFC  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
txterr27           0000000000402586  MAIN__                     26  txterr27.f90
txterr27           00000000004021DC  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          00007F083D474EC5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
txterr27           00000000004020D9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

To check if this is a compiler-specific problem, I rebuilt the example code under gfortran with:

```
gfortran -pedantic -Wall -fbacktrace -o txterr27 txterr27.f90
```

and got similar results:

```
 This works:

ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ  1ZZZZZZZZZZZ     1.000 AaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaa
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ 0.001ZZZZZZZZ

 This doesn't:
At line 26 of file txterr27.f90
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

Clearly there's no problem formatting the data, otherwise the write to stdout would fail. All I can think is that the `CRLF`s (`'/'`) are causing `write()` to render the result as an array not as a scalar. Writing an array to stdout would work fine (one entry per line) but it would fail if it was trying to write an array into a scalar.

The error messages from both `gfortran` and `ifort` leave a lot to be desired;  with apologies to the late Douglas Adams: "*Mostly Useless*"

Any ideas?

**Update:** On continued analysis, the problem is my understanding of what constitutes a 'record' in Fortran. Here's an updated illustration:

```
program TXTERR27A
    use iso_fortran_env, only: OUTPUT_UNIT    
    implicit none

    double precision :: F1, F2
    integer :: I1
    character (len=25), parameter :: A1 = 'AaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaa'

    character (len=250) :: A2
    character (len=250), dimension(5) :: A3

10  format(/, 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ', I3, 'ZZZZZZZZZZZ',     &
    F10.3, 1X, A25, /, 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ', F6.3, 'ZZZZZZZZ')
20  format('Result: [', A250, ']')
30  format('Result:', /, '[', *(A250, ']', /, '['))

    continue

    I1 = 1
    F1 = 1.0D0
    F2 = 1.0D-3
    A2 = ''
    A3 = ''

    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, *) "This works:"
    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, 10) I1, F1, A1, F2
    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, *)

    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, *) "Does this?"
    write(A3, 10) I1, F1, A1, F2
    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, 30) A3

    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, *) "This doesn't:"
    write(A2, 10) I1, F1, A1, F2
    write(OUTPUT_UNIT, 20) A2

    stop
end program TXTERR27A
```

This example shows that multiple records/strings are emitted when writing to an internal variable and that the problem (as suspected) was that `write()` is trying to put an array into a scalar. This makes sense if you consider `'/'` as a record separator, not as a simple `CRLF`:

```
 This works:

ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ  1ZZZZZZZZZZZ     1.000 AaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaa
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ 0.001ZZZZZZZZ

 Does this?
Result:
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ]
[ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ  1ZZZZZZZZZZZ     1.000 AaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaaAaaaa                                                                                                                                                                         ]
[ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ 0.001ZZZZZZZZ                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ]
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ]
[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ]
[
 This doesn't:
At line 34 of file txterr27.f90
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

This problem is obvious if you keep in mind the archaic record-oriented nature of Fortran I/O. This is easy to forget after long experience with languages with text I/O facilities developed after, say, 1969. Apologies for not seeing this straightaway.

Regardless, the important takeaway is to remember that `'/'` is a record separator and not look at it as Fortran's version of `\n`.

Comment: Are you just after someone confirming: yes, you can't write multiple records to the internal file?

Comment: I guess I'm unclear on what constitutes a 'record'. What I see is a single simple string but apparently '/' is a record separator, not just a CRLF. That would explain the behavior I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new line specifier `/` acts as a separator to the list-directed input. So you are trying to write three records to one internal file.

Only one is allowed for internal files, so after the first record, the end of the internal file is reached. That is, what `gfortran` is telling you.

Comment: Apologies if I seemed a bit grumpy before; I think we were missing what each other was saying.

Answer (score 1):

The slash edit descriptor (`/`) does not directly mark a new line (CRLF, or whatever appropriate for the system).  It merely indicates the end of transfer to (in the case of output) the current record.  You see this manifest on output to standard output as a new line as your processor is treating a record as being a line.

Internal files (character variables) are different.  Where you have a scalar character variable (`A2`) this defines a single record of length of the variable.  As you are attempting to write more than one record to this variable you see the error as you do.

However, it is possible to write more than one record to an internal file, as we can see in Fortran 2008 9.4:

> If the file is a character array, it is treated as a sequence of character array elements. Each array element, if any, is a record of the file.

You could, then, declare `A2` as being an array of size (at least) 3.

Alternatively, if you are truly after a new line in your scalar variable as a single record you could consider the `new_line` intrinsic, or the named constants `C_NEW_LINE` and `C_CARRIAGE_RETURN` of the intrinsic module `iso_c_binding`.

Comment: Thanks; as I'm trying to migrate our code to F2008, I'll have to look into `new_line` and `iso_c_binding`. I've been making liberal use of `adjustl()`,  `trim()`, and allocatable-length character variables to move our output away from tabular format. Writing to internal files is vital to that and it's easy to forget text I/O in Fortran is still fundamentally different from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar trouble before... When I tried to find a tag `</DATA>` in a data file
like

```
<DATA>
100 200 300
</DATA>
```

using a program like

```
program main
    character(50) :: str
    open( 10, file="some.xml", status="old" )
    do
        read( 10, * ) str
        print *, trim( str )
        if ( str == "</DATA>" ) then
            print *, "tag found!"
            exit
        endif
    enddo
    close(10)
end
```

I encountered an error

```
 <DATA>
 100
 <
At line 7 of file test.f90 (unit = 10, file = 'some.xml')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

and it took a long time to notice that Fortran doesn't like slash (/)... By changing the read statement as

```
read( 10, "(a)" ) str
```

the program gave the expected result

```
<DATA>
100 200 300
</DATA>
tag found!
```

Comment: This is perhaps a slightly different issue: `/` as a value separator in list-directed input terminates the input statement.